# Regrouping in Django Template With Grouping in views

Tags: django

I have  a model with different forginekey wish I could like to group it by student. I was successfully done that but in my template, I want to nested the result or regroup it by subject according to students.

model.py

```
class Result(models.Model):
    examtype = models.ForeignKey(ExamType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(SubjectAppointment, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    test = models.FloatField()
    exam = models.FloatField()
    total = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total = self.test + self.exam
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.matricnumber

    def get_result_total(self):
        return int(float(f'{self.test + self.exam}'))
```

views.py

```
def ReportView(request):
    template_name = 'teacher/report.html'
    score = Result.objects.values('student', 'exam', 'test', 'subject__subject__name').annotate(student_totalscore=Sum('total')).annotate(attending=Count('subject'))
   
    
    
    print(score)

    
    context = {

        'score': score,
        
        

    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

report.html

```
{% for s in score %}

   {% regroup score by s.student as student_list %}

                      
                        {% for a in student_list %}
                          <!-- {% for b in a.list %} -->
                          <tr>
                            <td>{{ b.subject__subject__name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ b.test }}</td>

                            <td>{{ b.exam }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                          </tr>
                            <!-- {% endfor %} -->
                          {% endfor %}
                    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? What do you want to achieve? Is something not working for you? What is `{% regroup score by s.student as student_list %}`?

Comment: I want select student accroding to the subject he or she did in Result Model. To give me final report for the students

Comment: What do you mean by "regrouping"? Can you give more examples?